# android get x-y co-ordinates from a Path

Tags: android, path

In my app I have an activity where I draw paths in canvas.and also I put all the paths into an `ArrayList<Path>.`
After drawing that I just send that `ArrayList<Path>` to another class to draw the same path in *different canvas.*

So there instead of using directly that Path I want to convert each Path to **x,y Co-ordinates** and from  that I able to draw all path.
**How can i do that?** 
part of my code is below,

```
private ArrayList<Path> _graphics = new ArrayList<Path>();
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        synchronized (_thread.getSurfaceHolder()) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                System.out.println("i'm in ACTION_DOWN ");
                path = new Path();
                path.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
                path.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());

            //_graphics.add(path);


                path.addCircle(event.getX(), event.getY(), 2,
                        Path.Direction.CCW);

            } 
            else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

                System.out.println("i'm in ACTION_MOVE ");
                path.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
                path.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
                _graphics.add(path);

            } 
            else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                System.out.println("i'm in ACTION_UP ");
                path.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());

            }

            return true;
            }
    }


    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        if (onSelect == true) {
            onSelect = false;
            _graphics.clear();
        }
        for (Path path : _graphics) {
            canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
            }
        }
```

`_graphics` is an `ArrayList<Path>` .

and **another question** is I also want to pass this `Arraylist<path>` through `Socket`, for that i have to convert this path to `byte[]`. **Is it possible to covert into byte[]?**

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not exactly what your looking for but this should help. It will display the x and y.

```
package com.mike.touch;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TouchActivity extends Activity {
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       TextView tv = new TextView(this);
       tv.setText("touch screen");
       setContentView(tv);
   }
   @Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
       TextView tv = new TextView(this);
       tv.setText("x="+event.getX()+"       y="+event.getY());
       setContentView(tv);

       return super.onTouchEvent(event);
   }
}
```